# Get data from a database that is between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, scripting

I am writing a system that will show data from a selected month. The user can select the month they want to look at, this then creates a URL something like this .com/page.php?month=03 the page as you can guess will take the idea and then use it to get data from the database from that month.

Now based on the month in the URL i am making to vars, $startdate $enddate start date based on this example is 2011-03-01, i then add 29 or 30 on to the days part of the date depending if the month has 31 or 30 days. Okay so i do the dates like this:

```
$startdate = mktime(0,0,0,date("$month"),date("01"),date("2011"));
if( $month==04 || $month==06 || $month==9 || $month==11)
{
    $enddate = mktime(0,0,0,date("$month"),date("01")+29,date("2011"));
}
else
{
    $enddate = mktime(0,0,0,date("$month"),date("01")+30,date("2011"));
}
```

Now when i try to get the data from the database with these variables it doesn't seem to work, this is the query:

```
$getresults = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE date BETWEEN $startdate AND $enddate ORDER BY date ASC");
```

The thing is if i change the vars to hard coded dates its works a treat... Anyone got any ideas? i was thinking it had something to do with the way the day is formatted? in my database its "Y-m-d" and is also the same in the php.

thank for any help people im really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mktime` produces dates as Unix timestamps (eg. '1317046059') but your table stored dates in a different format (eg. '2011-09-26'). To make your queries work, you will need to convert your timestamps into the appropriate format:

```
$enddate = date( 'Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date("$month"),date("01")+29,date("2011")) );
```

**Update:**

Based on your new comment that your dates are stored as timestamps in your database, you will need to format your dates in this manner:

```
$enddate = date( 'Y-m-d h:i:s', mktime(0,0,0,date("$month"),date("01")+29,date("2011")) );
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but now where i echo the data it's 1970... ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Yeah i used your code, $enddate = date( 'Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date("$month"),date("01")+29,date("2011")) ); and then used echo the print out the dates, now my dates are 1970-01-01
1970-01-01 instead of them being sept 2011. Hope thats a bit better.

Comment: Okay so i sorted that problem so forget i said anything :P thanks for the help.

Comment: Well i jumped the gun a little bit. I have used the code you provided and the database is still not being queried. The date field of the database is 'timestamp' if that helps?

Comment: It just doesn't like the dates being in Vars and i don't want to hard code for every month of the year.

Can you see anything wrong with the query?

thanks again for your help.

Comment: Instead of `BETWEEN` you should use greater-than and less-than as advised in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-date.html). Additionally, your date variables should be encapsulated in single-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a couple var_dump statements in key places to evaluate you code.  This way, you can know EXACTLY what your data looks like, including its format, then you can figure out how to format that date the way you need to.