# how to get data between two date with two different year?

Tags: php, mysql

My query below doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE date between '12/30/2013' and '01/05/2014'
```

But when I change the order of dates like in this query below, it seems to be working

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE date between '01/01/2014' and '01/05/2014'
```

What is the correct way to use date ranges in SELECTs?

Comment: Can you try with `SELECT * FROM test where date between '30/12/2013' and '01/05/2014'`

Comment: Not working means? error or no result?

Comment: why dont you try `<` and `>` operators ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555484/get-data-from-a-database-that-is-between-two-dates?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

It won't work because the dates are not ISO 8601 formatted: "2013-12-30" for example.

The `BETWEEN` clause makes a string comparaison, so you need either to use a correct date format in your database, or format the dates with `DATE_FORMAT()` or `STR_TO_DATE(str,format)`.

**Edit**: 
Try this query, which will work if you store dates as strings formatted as `%m/%d/%Y`, which is a bad idead, MySQL has a built-in `DATE` format :

```
SELECT * FROM test where STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') between STR_TO_DATE('01/01/2014', '%m/%d/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2014','%m/%d/%Y');
```

The `DATE_FORMAT` MySQL takes a `DATE` or `DATETIME` value as first argument, which you don't use, that's why it didn't work (in addition to the '$' you used instead of '%' before 'Y')

Comment: SELECT * FROM `test` where date between DATE_FORMAT('01/01/2014','%m/%d/%Y') and DATE_FORMAT('01/05/2014','%m/%d/$Y')  it try this but not working

Answer (score 1):

Use php and sql together to get the result as below

```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('12/30/2013'));

$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('01/05/2014'));

$sql    =   "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE date between '".$date1."' 
                     and '".$date2."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

`select * from test where date between "2013-12-30" and "2014-01-05"`

This will work fine